# Give ctrl + shift + esc the same level of system interrupt as ctrl + alt + delete

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1

If you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>, the task manager opens. However, this doesn't have the same level of system interrupt as pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You cannot.  Its by design that that ctrl+shift+esc isn't a system level interrupt

Comment: @Ramhound Why? Is there something bad about giving it higher interrupt?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it.  But the lack of it being a system interrupt is clearly a design choice.

Comment: I haven't tried this but perhaps you have as you seem to like ctrl-alt-delete. What if you can't do ctrl-shift-esc, and you do ctrl-alt-delete and you then click to start task manager? Does it start? If not, it may be that when all hell is breaking loose in windows, such that ctrl-shift-esc isn't even starting task manager, then you can't just do what ctrl-shift-esc does which is sit in windows as it is and start up task manager. the c-a-d screen is almost like the normal gui is somewhat shut off or paused perhaps, it's -that- low level.

Comment: I've read that Control-Alt-Delete calls Winlogon and that it would respond either by showing Windows Security (aka, the login screen) or the Task Manager, depending on user preference. Control-Shift-Escape also goes through Winlogon though, however it always calls Task Manager. So, as for design reasons, there's the fact they have different functions.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard  I wonder if the idea that ctrl-alt-delete can open task manager is a myth. Googling throws up nothing on it apart from some links or articles with titles suggesting that you can, but then some wollys "yeah you can , with ctrl-shift-escape". So, looks like you can't with ctrl-alt-delete (though i'm fine with ctrl-shift-escape).

Comment: @barlop a myth? Maybe, in Windows 8.1 there is no way to just go to Task Manager from Ctrl-Alt-Del, but I can assure you that you were always able to do that [in XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281980). Also, this feature is related slightly with the welcome screen, which can be manipulated as stated [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308226).

Comment: @DoktoroReichard  oh i see, yes I remember now win xp doing different things.. It seems Win7 won't though.